# Program is rceiving PAM_PERM_DENIED (7) when authenticating against Active Directory, while ssh works

Tags: linux, active-directory, pam

I am using an Active Domain `jamie_ad1.net`, and I have a user greg there.
When I `ssh -l greg@jamie_ad1.net x.x.x.x` I am successfully being logged in.
When, however, I am authenticating the user in my program, my `process_user()` function (below) returns error 7 (`PAM_PERM_DENIED` - The caller does not possess the required authority.)

What do I do wrong? Note that during `ssh`, it is `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` that is being used. I am using the same PAM service name `"system_auth"` in my program, too (and I also used "sshd", and "login" - all failed.)

```
static int process_user( const char* uname, const char* pwd )
{
    int             rv = 0 ;
    struct pam_conv conv ;
    pam_handle_t*   pamh = NULL;

    conv.conv = &pamauth_conv ;
    conv.appdata_ptr = ( void* )pwd ;

    if (
        (( rv = pam_start( "system-auth", uname, &conv, &pamh )) == PAM_SUCCESS )
        && (( rv = pam_acct_mgmt(pamh, PAM_SILENT | PAM_DISALLOW_NULL_AUTHTOK )) == PAM_SUCCESS )
        && (( rv = pam_authenticate( pamh, PAM_SILENT | PAM_DISALLOW_NULL_AUTHTOK )) == PAM_SUCCESS )
       )
        ...

   pam_end( pamh, rv ) ;

   ...
}
```

Below I am showing the convesation funcion used by `process_user()`
While under `gdb` I see that `num_msg` is 1, and the `msg[ 0 ]->msg` is `"Password: "`, and that the function properly sets `p[ 0 ].resp` as strduped password (I have checked that the password is correct.)

```
static int pamauth_conv( int num_msg, const struct pam_message** msg, struct pam_response** resp, void* appdata_ptr )
{
   int                  rv = PAM_SUCCESS ;
   struct pam_response* p = NULL ;
   int                  i ;

   p = calloc( num_msg, sizeof( struct pam_response )) ;
   if ( p == NULL )
      rv = PAM_BUF_ERR ;
   else
   {
      for ( i = 0; ( rv == PAM_SUCCESS ) && ( i < num_msg ); i++ )
         if ( strcmp( msg[ i ]->msg, "Password: " ) == 0 ) /* support password conversation only */
         {
            p[ i ].resp = strdup(( char* )appdata_ptr ) ;
            if ( p[ i ].resp == NULL )
               rv = PAM_BUF_ERR;
         }
   }

   if ( rv == PAM_SUCCESS )
      *resp = p ;
   else if ( p )
   {
      for ( i = 0; i < num_msg; i++ )
         if ( p[ i ].resp )
            free( p[ i ].resp ) ;

      free( p ) ;
   }

   return rv ;
}
```

**NOTE:** The `pam_acct_mgmt()` call returns SUCCESS, so it confirms that the greg@jamie_ad1.net user exists. It is `pam_authenticate()` that complains.

Contents of `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, which is exactly the same as `/etc/pam.d/password-auth' :

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Contents of `/etc/pam.d/sshd`
    #%PAM-1.0
    auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
    auth       include      password-auth
    account    required     pam_nologin.so
    account    include      password-auth
    password   include      password-auth

```
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session required pam_lastlog.so showfailed
```

Comment: How do you know ssh is using `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and nothing else?  I would typically expect sshd to use its own service configuration (`/etc/pam.d/sshd`) which would include this common configuration and add its service specific config...

Comment: @PeterBrittain: Thank  you for the interest. It is because sshd, login, etc, include system-auth or password-auth. In my case both files are the same. I have also mentioned that I called `pam_start( "sshd" ...)` as well, and the result was the same.

Comment: SSH client might use preconfigured Kerberos infrastructure to log into the Active Directory. Examine `/etc/krb5.conf` to see if it has configuration for domain `jamie_ad1.net`. Or alternatively run `klist` right after successful ssh session and check if it displays active Kerberos tickets. In that case you might need to learn using `pam_krb5`.

Comment: @void: `/etc/krb5.conf` contains proper configuration. However `klist` shows this: `klist: No credentials cache found (ticket cache FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_16777216)` - BTW `/tmp/krb5cc_16777216` does not exist.

Comment: @void: I have noticed that there was lingering klist that should not be there. So after removing it, and re-initializing everything from scratch, I am getting this output from `klist` after successfully `ssh-ing` (I am putting <lf> at the end of each line to make it easier to reconstruct it:)

    `Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_16777216`<lf>
    `Default principal: grg@JAMIE_AD1.NET`<lf>
<lf>
    `Valid starting     Expires            Service principal`<lf>
    `08/02/16 15:09:59  08/03/16 01:10:05 krbtgt/JAMIE_AD1.NET@JAMIE_AD1.NET`<lf>
            `renew until 08/09/16 15:09:59`<lf>

Comment: @Grzegorz: Your observation that "pam_acct_mgmt() call returns SUCCESS" might mean that at least a part of PAM subsystem is configured to use Kerberos. Are there any files under `/etc/pam.d/` that refer to `pam_krb5.so`?

Comment: @void: none has any reference to this or any module containing 'krb' in the name. Only winbind. I will update the ticket to show the contents of the `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/sshd', and annotation that `password-auth` is the same as `system-auth`

Comment: How did you determine that `pam_acct_mgmt()` returns success?  In the code you posted, it will never be called if `pam_authenticate()` fails.

Comment: @nephtes: Because I have reversed the code before. I will correct the example, so it won't be a road block for anyone. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logging in with SSH client works because it does not use PAM subsystem for  authentication on the external AD host. SSH client checks `GSSAPIAuthentication` flag in its config (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `/etc/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`) and calls GSSAPI library. GSSAPI uses Kerberos which is installed and correctly configured on the Linux host that your program runs on.

If the program purpose is to authenticate user credentials against Active Directory then it should do the same and call [GSSAPI](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.14/doc/appdev/gssapi.html). An alternative way (possibly easier to use) could be authenticating over [LDAP API](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap). Just note that AD installations sometimes reject simple plaintext authentication over unencrypted LDAP and require SASL-based authentication or SSL connection.

Call to `pam_start( "system-auth",` in your code means "authenticate user in the same way as other PAM-based services on this Linux host do". In order to make it work one should contact Linux host administrator (that one who configured Kerberos client) and ask her/him to complete [integration with the Active Directory](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Active_Directory_Integration). The result of successful setup would be that PAM-based services (like login, su, sshd and so on) will start understanding AD credentials and so will do your code. This approach also has its limitations:

- your program will always depend on working AD integration setup of the host it runs on, i.e. proper Kerberos, PAM and/or Samba configuration,
- "system-auth" is a name of PAM service specific to RedHat-based distributions, it might be missing on Debian-based systems.

If the code only needs authenticate to AD with PAM subsystem and using "system-auth" service is not a requirement then the following minimal configuration might help. Again, without qualified Linux admin it would be quite a risky venture:

1. Install pam_krb5 package on Red Hat, libpam-krb5 on Debian.
2. Find exact location of `pam_krb5.so`, on my Ubuntu box it was
   `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_krb5.so`.
3. Create a new service description file `/etc/pam.d/krb5auth` with the following contents (copied from the [man page](https://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/pam-krb5/pam-krb5.html)):

```
auth            sufficient      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
session         required        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
account         required        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
password        sufficient      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
```

4. Test the new service, I would recommend a quick Python session with
   [python-pam](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pam/). Enter user name either as 'greg' or as
   'greg@JAMIE_AD1.NET', uppercase is important for Kerberos sometimes.
5. Change the pam_start() call in your code to use `pam_start( "krb5auth",` and cross your fingers.

Comment: Dear void: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure if it takes me out of the woods, but your answer seems to be reasonable, and being also encouraged by two upvotes, I will give you what is due to you. I will let you know somewhere in the future if I make it working with your help. Thanks again!

Comment: @Grzegorz: Thank you for the award. I am sorry that I could not fully resolve your problem but that comes out of two major obstacles: 1) it is not clear which exactly function you are trying to implement, 2) PAM-based approach requires admin skills that we both seem to not possess (I did never see a Linux box integrated into AD environment up to the PAM level).

Comment: @Grzegorz: Nevertheless, there are some additional clues that might help with the code snippet above: you can cease trying to set up 'system-auth' service and create a special PAM service that is only used for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the edition and the help! Your post helped to be convinced that it is doable, and that the problem is in the code. I will add a new answer, but I will leave your answer as the solution for you put a lot of work to it, and will be definitively a help for others seeking an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to user void for his help and hard work.

At the end the problem was ended up in the library in the set of local libraries that were linked to the final product. Note: It is **not** something from the system. It is a local library that was not needed anymore but was overwriting some of the PAM functions needed for Active Directory (LDAP, for example, worked okay.) It is user void that gave me the courage to test configuration, and then try to limit the example to the bare minimum, as shown below (I should have done it from the beginning!)

The example above, when compiled using command `gcc example.c -o example -lpam` will work perfectly fine. The problem I had with this example was that I was compiling it within the system that was pulling into output a lot of other libraries.

After removing the 'bad' library from the list of libraries (it took some time to do that...) the final product works well, and logins into Active Directory fine.

Thank you for all of you who spent some time looking into it.